# Monitor Refresh Token for web push FCM and replace that with the old one in DB

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently I am trying to do a web push ( Push notifications ) NOT APP only though browser

I have generated the Application Token 
[Token generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBVzH.png)

Then saving that token to db. Now, issues is when I clear my cache the token changes. How can I monitor thus replacing the new token with old one(replace only that particular token)?

Here is current code app.js

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "*********",
    databaseURL: "*********",
    projectId: "t********",
    storageBucket: "******",
    messagingSenderId: "******"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const messaging = firebase.messaging();

  messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function(){

    console.log("have permission");
    alert("have permission");

    return messaging.getToken();
  })
  .then(function(token){
    console.log(token);
    var newToken = token;
   alert("newToken");
  })
  .catch(function(err){

console.log("error Occurred");
alert("error occurred");

  })

  messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
console.log("onMessage",payload);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation on monitoring token refresh](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#monitor-token-refresh):

> The `onTokenRefresh` callback fires whenever a new token is generated, so calling `getToken` in its context ensures that you are accessing a current, available registration token.
>
> ```
> // Callback fired if Instance ID token is updated.
> messaging.onTokenRefresh(function() {
>   messaging.getToken()
>   .then(function(refreshedToken) {
>     console.log('Token refreshed.');
>     // Indicate that the new Instance ID token has not yet been sent to the
>     // app server.
>     setTokenSentToServer(false);
>     // Send Instance ID token to app server.
>     sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
>     // ...
>   })
>   .catch(function(err) {
>     console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
>     showToken('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
>   });
> });
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..I did try this but it is not  getting triggered when ever I am clearing the history thus updating the token to new one ...it is not getting triggered .where I need to put this code up

Comment: This code will trigger when the token refreshes. That is *not* on every page load. When you add the code to an existing page, the token already exists - so the code won't trigger. That's why you **also** need the `then()` that you already have.

Comment: I can clearly see the token got refreshed in console when I cleared my cache  but the function didn't trigger ..any additional thoughts

Comment: I can understand when the token refreshes for an Android app, but when does this event happen in a web js-app?

Comment: any way to get the old token in the refresh context?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use the local storage to save the first token

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) {
  if (permission === 'granted') {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.
   // Save token in the local storage
  } else {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
 }
});
```

In the refresh context, you could retrieve the previously saved token to replace it by the new one.